# Simplicial complex with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Is there any example of a simplicial complex with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?

(Preferably a “simple” example with as few vertices as possible.)

So far I learnt about $RP^2$, with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks.

Comment: The simplest example is probably a triangulation of an appropriate lens space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space

Comment: Simplicial complex? Triangle with all edges identified as you go counterclockwise.

Comment: Side note: for any group $G$ there's a simplicial complex with $G$ as its fundamental group. See: [Eilenberg-MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space).

Answer (score 2):

Let us see why Ted Shifrin's suggestion works. So let $X$ be the topological space obtained from the following identifications:

$\hskip2in$ [image]

<strike>Then, for instance, taking the barycentric subdivision of the triangle, it is clear that $X$ is a simplicial complex.</strike>

---

**Edit:** As pointed out by Cheerful Parsnip the barycentric subdivision of the triangle doesn't turn $X$ into a simplicial complex but the [second barycentric subdivision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEXuO.png) does: prove that each triangle in the second barycentric subdivision embeds in $X$ and that if any two distinct such triangles intersect, their intersection is either an edge or a point; this last property fails if we use the first barycentric subdivision.

---

Let us see why $\pi_1(X)\cong\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Let $Y$ be the space obtained by taking three copies of the above triangle $T,T',T''$;(say $T'$ and $T''$ have edges $a',b',c'$ and $a'',b'',c''$, respectively, each having the same orientation as in the drawing above), then gluing $a,a',a''$ respecting orientations, and finally gluing $b,b',b''$ and $c,c',c''$ the same way. Then $Y$ is a $3$-fold covering of $X$(can you see why?).

It is easy to see(a drawing will help) that $Y$ is homeomorphic to the space obtained by taking a sphere $S$ and a closed disk $D$ and gluing $\partial D$ along the equator of $S$.

Let $V$ be the union of the upper hemisphere of $S$ and $D$. Then $V$ is homemorphic to a sphere, $V\cup S= Y$ and $V\cap S$ is a disk, thus $Y$ is simply connected because of Seifert-Van Kampen theorem.

Thus we get that as $Y$ is a $3$-fold covering of $X$, $\pi_1(X)$ must have size $3$, and thus it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

If you want to do this for any $n>0$ ($n$ not necessarily prime), do the same construction(using an $n$-gon instead), and show that there is a deck transformation of order $n$.

Comment: Thanks. Is the diagram you show already a simplicial complex? Or do I have to do further subdivision and triangulation.

Comment: I think first barycentric subdivision may not be enough to make it a simplicial complex?

Comment: @yoyostein, show that the restriction of the quotient map $\pi:T\rightarrow X$ to each of the triangles of the barycentric subdivision of $T$ is one-to-one.

Comment: This is not a simplicial complex under the first barycentric subdivision. The edges that connect the middle vertex to the outer three vertices actually all have the same endpoints in the quotient. You need to do a double barycentric subdivision to get it to be a simplicial complex.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip You're right, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @yoyostein yes, the first barycentric subdivision is not enough, check my edit.